# Wifi connected but no internet access in ubuntu 22.10.But ethernet is working well

Tags: wireless, internet

Recently I've upgraded my OS from ubuntu 22.04 to 22.10 . After upgrading wifi is being connected but there is no internet access. Another thing it is working well for ethernet. I have connected to my mobile wifi

Comment: v22.10 has reached EOL see: https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/06/14/ubuntu-22-10-kinetic-kudu-reaches-end-of-life-on-july-20-2023/